# UWP Mediabox - a few questions

Tags: windows, stream, uwp, iot, mediacenter

I have a question to you and I really hope you can provide me some information.
I wish to build a media center because I have not found any possibilities to cast my stuff straight to the big screen from my Windows mobile phone.

Off course there is the wireless display adapter from Microsoft but I wish not to cast my whole display to my tv.

After testing a few product (Amazon fire tv box, apple tv 3, display dock and the wireless dock) I came to the conclusion that I can not have an all in one solution which fits my perceptions.

From that point I thought that I have to build my own "tv application".
Ok ok... There is kodi(xbmc) and so on... But I think this is just making a detour.

Following features must be included:

- running on Windows 10
- Cast music, videos and pictures.
- Ability to launch and download windows store apps.
- Project Rome implementation to share data across devices.

Seems possible but here´s one big problem... 
If we are talking about mediaboxes, we do talk about those small boxes besides your tv. Instead off building a micro ATX setup, I want to take this to the next level... using IoT (Raspberry Pi 3).
Using IoT may have some advantages but there are a few disadvantages I have to worry about.

- Will Windows 10 work properly on IoT (advantages - disadvantages)
- Media streaming?
- ARM architecture
- Bluetooth, WIFI, Ethernet connectivity

I have never ever worked on IoT before, so I am kinda noob again. I´am asking for some advices to make this possible.

- [UWP] How can I stream data (e.g. video, music, images) to another application?
- [UWP] Implement a remote control - just like the amazon fire tv controler ?
- Advantages - Disadvantages of using Windows 10 on a Raspberry Pi ?
- Using windows 10 default applications (Groove Music, Images, Videos - Application) to play incomming data?

What do you think? Is it possible to create a Mediacenter which is running on a raspberry pi using windows 10?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think its possible you are looking to reinvent the wheel. However, that said, Im reasonably sure that an IoT machine isnt designed to do what you are hoping for. While they can access the UWP API, dont confuse this win10 version with WinRT - Win10 IoT is barebones and not designed to be used as a "standard" computer

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have read some very interesting articles about Windows 10 IoT. It is far away from being a desktop-oriented operation system.

Comment: But you have the ability to use many function from the UWP base. It could be possible. I think I have to buy a raspberry pi and see what I can do. I hope WIFI Direct is working properly ^^

Comment: Definetly wise, tinker away - its free after all - and if you can't achieve what you want then you can always fall back on xbmc or plex. IoT is generally designed to add networking capability to otherwise unconnected devices

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward idea would be to create an always-running app with a [MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/media-playback) with a [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.source.aspx) property that can be set programmatically by a remote control app. A remote control app could also control the pause, play, next, previous actions.

Be aware that there is no hardware video acceleration support for Raspberry Pi on Windows IoT Core yet, and probably that also won't come soon. There are other devices that do have proper video drivers (look at the hardware support page of Windows IoT Core).

Also be aware that there is no Windows Store on Windows IoT Core, unless you are an OEM (then you can publish your properly signed apps in an official way to devices that are managed by you).

A simpler way would be to buy a Windows 10 box from aliexpress. Then you can use Miracast to stream your screen, install apps from the App Store and play films directly on it, for example using Kodi for which remote control apps exist.